# Mercurial largefiles not working on Windows Server 2008

Tags: iis, mercurial, windows-server-2008

I'm trying to get the largefiles extension working on a mercurial server under Windows Server 2008 / IIS 7.5 with the hgweb.wsgi script.

When I clone a repo with largefiles locally (but using `https://domain/`, not a file system path) everything gets cloned fine, but when I try it on a different machine I get `abort: remotestore: largefile XXXXX is missing`

Here's the verbose output:

```
requesting all changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 1 changesets with 177 changes to 177 files
calling hook changegroup.lfiles: <function checkrequireslfiles at 0x0000000002E00358>
updating to branch default
resolving manifests
getting .hglf/path/to.file
...
177 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
getting changed largefiles
getting path/to.file:c0c81df934cd72ca980dd156984fa15987e3881d
abort: remotestore: largefile c0c81df934cd72ca980dd156984fa15987e3881dis missing
```

Both machines have the extension working. I've tried disabling the firewall but that didn't help. Do I have to do anything to set up the extension besides adding it to mercurial.ini?

Edit: If I delete the files from the server's `AppData\Local\largefiles\` directory, I get the same error when cloning on the server, unless I use a filesystem path to clone, in which case the files are added back to `AppData\Local\largefiles\'

Edit 2: Here's the debug output and traceback:

```
177 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
getting changed largefiles
using http://domain
sending capabilities command
getting largefiles: 0/75 lfile (0.00%)
getting path/to.file:64f2c341fb3b1adc7caec0dc9c51a97e51ca6034
sending statlfile command

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 87, in _runcatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 685, in _dispatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 467, in runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 775, in _runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 746, in checkargs
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 682, in <lambda>
  File "mercurial\util.pyo", line 463, in check
  File "mercurial\commands.pyo", line 1167, in clone
  File "mercurial\hg.pyo", line 400, in clone
  File "mercurial\extensions.pyo", line 184, in wrap
  File "hgext\largefiles\overrides.pyo", line 629, in hgupdate
  File "hgext\largefiles\lfcommands.pyo", line 416, in updatelfiles
  File "hgext\largefiles\lfcommands.pyo", line 398, in cachelfiles
  File "hgext\largefiles\basestore.pyo", line 80, in get
  File "hgext\largefiles\remotestore.pyo", line 56, in _getfile
Abort: remotestore: largefile 64f2c341fb3b1adc7caec0dc9c51a97e51ca6034 is missing
```

The `_getfile` function throws an exception because the `statlfile` command returns that the file wasn't found.

I've never used python myself, so I don't know what I'm doing while trying to debug this :D

AFAIK the `statlfile` command gets executed on the server so I can't debug it from my local machine. I've tried running `python -m win32traceutil` on the server, but it doesn't show anything. I also tried setting `accesslog` and `errorlog` in the server's mercurial config file, but it doesn't generate them.

I run hg through the hgweb.wsgi script, and I have no idea if/how I can get into the python debugger using that, but if I could get the debugger running on the server I could narrow down the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out, the extension tries to write temporary files to `%windir%\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local`, which was causing permission errors. The call was wrapped in a try-catch block that ended up returning the "file not found" error.

Answer (score -1):

I'm just posting this for anyone else coming into the thread from a search.

There's currently an issue using the largefiles extension in the mercurial python module when hosted via IIS. See [this post](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issue/2593/cant-push-over-30mb-to-iis-via-https) if you're encountering issues pushing large changesets (or large files) to IIS via TortoiseHg.

The problem ultimlately turns out to be a bug in SSL processing introduced Python 2.7.3 (probably explaining why there are so many unresolve posts of people looking for problems with Mercurial). Rolling back to Python 2.7.2 let me get a little further ahead (blocked at 30Mb pushes instead of 15Mb), but to properly solve the problem I had to install the [IISCrypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/Default.aspx) utility to completely disable transfers over SSLv2.